# Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies

I find the following occurring bug weird.

When I post a comment I start with @someone.

But for some reason this does not always get into the text.

I get no error message but it is not there.

In the beginning it occurred so little that I started to doubt if I perhaps forgot it.
But it occurred more and more and even with edits I am now not always able to do it.
It seems to appear more often to people with a rep below 100 if I'm not mistaken.

Assuming I do not have a keylog or something I post this.

Comment: The solution is to type !user instead of @user if you wish to include the user's name but the system removes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the "official" SE specification of @ pings see [this MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on how comment replies work. Most likely what is happening in your case is that the software is deleting the recipient since the author is already a *default* recipient, so the ping is redundant. You can notice this in advance since completion will not work ("Tab" completes usernames here).

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a bug. @s are automatically stripped if, for example, you're trying to address someone in a comment to one of their questions: they already get a notification, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: To add on this, if there have been *other* participants in the conversation the system will allow you to ping the poster to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: That is not consistant with it occuring sometimes and sometimes not in the same thread.

Comment: But thanks for the answers/comments , I see now its not ( a complete ? ) bug and has meaning.

Comment: It is not a bug at all, @mick. It is your unfamiliarity with the software.