# What does it mean if I try to tag a user in the comments and it doesn't highlight or record?

Tags: support, user-interface, comment-replies

I tried to tag a user in a comment replying to his previous comment.  Usually if I type @UserNa.... the name will appear in a pop-up field.  But when I tried to tag one user, the name didn't pop up.  When I saved the comment, the tag vanished.

Comment: Related older question: [Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6281)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The software tries to avoid @name syntax when it is not needed.

Presumably you were in one of these two cases:

- You were the original poster and there was only one other user that had commented.
- You were addressing the original poster of the post (and there weren't others commenting already).

In these cases, the other user is notified no matter what and the @name is not needed. Thus  it is not proposed and even suppressed when the comment is submitted.

Comment: So basically I spammed the guy, by trying to repost a few times.  Live and learn.

Comment: Yes, they were notified of each comment. But most likely it's not that big a deal as all the notifications won't show up separately when they check.