# Quoting people in the comments

Tags: support, comment-replies

I put this down as support for categories...apologies in advance if that is incorrect, I don't know what else to tag this with.

How do you quote people in the comments now? I put "@" and then the person's username on here but what happens is that what comes after the "@" is now deleted. Before this used to work.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're actually trying to ask, but the first guess that it might be related to this: [Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6281)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a quote, but rather a way to ping the user with the name after the @ (in the sense that they will receive a notification in their SE inbox that you pinged them). You can do this for at most one user, and sometimes it is removed when it is unnecessary. This primarily happens when the only people commenting on the post are you and the poster, and they will automatically be pinged. There is a discussion of the purpose and basic usage in [this Meta SE FAQ post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). There is some additional discussion on removal when you are only commenting with the poster [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation).

Comment: Also Mike, "pinging" a user in comments notifies that user of your comment/question.