# How to put a math formula into a comment to a question on StackExchange

Tags: discussion, mathjax, comment

Is there a way to write math formulae in a comment to a question on StackExchange (Mathematics Meta). I'm sure this must have been asked before but my search didn't come up with anything (a reference to a previous post would be good)? For example I tried copying formula from the question into the comments box but not all parts were transcribed correctly.

Many Thanks

Comment: $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.

Comment: The comments support the usual texting language...what formula did you have trouble with?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  What formula, exactly, did you have trouble with?  Edit your post to include that formula...that way we can see what makes it difficult to insert it into a comment.  Also, this has nothing to do with set-theory.

Comment: I appreciate it is off topic, but I couldn't find where the correct place to post it was - I guessed people on Set-Theory would know! I copied from a post on Forcing "If p⊩Iϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n) and p∈G", but for example the superscripts and subscripts didn't work. Thanks for the replies I will ask on Math Meta. $\le \in $

Comment: You do the same thing in comments that you do in actual posts: use dollar signs and LaTeX.

Comment: @LittleCheese : Typing `$\phi(x'_1,...,x'_n)$` I get $\phi(x'_1,...,x'_n)$ . The riddle is that copy and paste doesn't work, unless you copy a *source* MathJax code to which you don't have access in comments. In a Q or A you can grab this code after you clicked on Edit.

Comment: @LittleCheese Can I ask what you did, that it didn't work?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that MathJax *should* try to render comments as well, but it doesn't succeed on every platform.  Notably, the stackexchange phone app seems to struggle with this, and I feel as though I remember hearing complaints about safari as well in the past.  In the current internet era, it is recommended to use one of chrome, edge, or opera for best experiences in websites.  That is because there are frequent (*though usually minor*) discrepancies in how javascript, css, and even sometimes html function in different browsers and not every site tries to cater to older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for migrating my question to the right place (whoever did it!). Ah, Kurt G gives the solution - I copied the presented formula in the answer into comments, but I should have copied the source MathJax code from the answer to get the formula to show correctly.

Comment: As for "*...unless you copy a source MathJax code to which you don't have access in the comments...*" @KurtG. that is not entirely accurate.  If you were to right-click on some rendered text you can select [Show Math As] -> [TeX Commands] and this will open a popup with the specific MathJax used to typeset this.  You can copy that... assuming of course that you are on a browser which supports this (*again, RIP to app users*)

Comment: @JMoravitz . +1 for this nice hint.

Comment: regarding Mathjax. There is a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JMoravitz: just adding that it is best not to use the phone app. Rather one should use the site directly in phone browser.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Can you copy paste MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33229) and [Can you copy paste tex code from the question without going the "view source" route?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217) (You can find also some other related posts here on meta.)

Comment: @JMoravitz : please allow me one question as you seem to be a real stack exchange tech expert : quite often I notice that when I start a comment with `@username` this beginning gets deleted. Why could that be ? Bad browser ?

Comment: @KurtG. See, for example, [Why does `@someone` sometimes disappear from comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6281).